# Update ChildView in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am working with an application where I have an ExpandableListView, in this there are some childViews as well. In each ChildView  I have number of edittexts when I comes to change the value in these edittext, it produce problem. when I try to open keyboard on clicking its not open. I want to change the value of every edittext and also to reflect these values to Expandableview.

Here is my code:

public class PatientMedicationExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

```
private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader;
private TreeMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
private View view;
private TextView editText;
private static int count=0;
private int[] images;

public PatientMedicationExpandableAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                          TreeMap<String, List<String>> listChildData, int[] images) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    this.images=images;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}


@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
}

public Context get_context() {
    return _context;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_expadable_medication_child_item, null);
        view = convertView;
    }
    holder.txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    holder.editchild = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editchild);
    holder.editchild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.editchild.post(
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) _context.getSystemService(_context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(holder.editchild.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                            holder.editchild.requestFocusFromTouch();
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
    UiUtils.applyTypceFace(_context,holder.txtListChild);
    holder.txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    final View groupView=convertView;
    final String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_exapandable_medication_group_item, null);
    }

    holder.editContentImageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editContentImageView);
    holder.editContentImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
            final LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
            final Dialog d=new Dialog(_context);
            d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            d.setContentView(view);
            d.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            d.setCancelable(false);

            try {
                for (String key : _listDataChild.keySet()) {
                    List<String> value = _listDataChild.get(key);
                    for (String val : value) {
                        EditText et = new EditText(_context);
                        et.setText(val);
                        et.setMinLines(1);
                        et.setMaxLines(3);
                        ll.addView(et);
                        System.out.println(val);
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Exception "+e);
            }


            (view.findViewById(R.id.add_ok)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                }
            });

            (view.findViewById(R.id.new_Field)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    editText= new TextView(_context);
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    editText.setId(Integer.valueOf(count));
                    ll.addView(editText);
                    d.setContentView(view);
                    count++;
                }
            });

            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.add_no)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });
            d.show();

        }
    });
    holder.lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    holder.lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    UiUtils.applyTypceFace(_context,holder.lblListHeader);

    holder.imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconImageView
    );
    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(_context.getResources().getDrawable(images[groupPosition]));

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView txtListChild;
    private TextView lblListHeader;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ImageView editContentImageView;
    private ImageView editchild;

}
```

}